# get values of multidimensional json array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get the value of two variables from an json array. The array becomes sended with ajax then decoded and "saved" into `$jsonarray`. Then I try to get the `volume` and the `symbol` variables from the array and insert them into my database. I dont understand the syntax of this `$jsonarray->result->{"quote"}->symbol` and tried any times how its right but the error wont disappear.

**thats my array:**

```
{"query":{"count":1,"created":"2016-02-15T15:11:47Z","lang":"de-DE","results":{"quote":{"symbol":"ZN","Ask":"2.05","Bid":"1.78","Volume":"13214","PercentChange":"+0.56%"}}}}
```

**relevant php piece:**

```
$jsonString = $_POST['mydata'];
$jsonarray = json_decode($jsonString[0]['query']);
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO volume (stocksymbol, volume, time) VALUES ( ?, ?, now())')) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $jsonarray->result->{"quote"}->symbol, $jsonarray->result->{"quote"}->Volume);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: `$jsonarray->result->quote->symbol`

Comment: You should perhaps peruse the manual for how `bind_param` needs to be called: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Now that you've fixed the cause of the issue... is there still any problem...?!

Comment: I take that as a "no"?! You've basically removed your question with your last edits...

Comment: When I run `var_dump($jsonarray);` I get `NULL` I search now where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure this line is correct? 
`$jsonarray = json_decode($jsonString[0]['query']);`

In this case, you should access to the result by: 
`$jsonarray->query->results->...`

Comment: Yes thank you thats the problem, I am trying to search now for the reason

Comment: The JSON object has only one first level property: query. 
It's not `{"count":1, "created": "today", "lang": "AZ", "results": {}}`

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
/* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $jsonarray->result->{"quote"}->symbol, $jsonarray->result->{"quote"}->Volume);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try and decode your JSON as an associative array instead. Assuming that `$_POST['mydata']` contains the JSON string you showed us, try this:

```
$jsonString = $_POST['mydata']; 
$jsonarray = json_decode($jsonString, TRUE);
```

This way, you can access the values in a more consistent way:

```
$stmt->bind_param(
     "si", 
     $jsonarray['query']['results']['quote']['symbol'], 
     $jsonarray['query']['results']['quote']['Volume']
);
```